# Call a specific functionality before each function returns in a c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class

I am writing a class that returns URLs generated for a web project.

I have around 200 functions that return URLs. At the end of each of these 200 functions, I have to call a specific function to process and validate the URL.

Can this be automated? I don't want to miss this in any of the 200 functions.

Comment: Maybe put all the urls into an object and do a FOR EACH to loop through and hit all of them.

Comment: The best fix for this is not having 200 functions to return URLs in the first place - I'm sure it can be refactored down to a maximum of 2-3 methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automate it using a programming technique known as [Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). There are a couple of AOP tools out there, and one of the most well known for C# is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) and there is an edition that you can use for free (note that I have no affiliation with PostSharp).

Basically what happens is that you add an Attribute to the class in question and PostSharp takes that attribute and the class and generates a new class during the compilation phase which performs both actions. Its a very powerful technique that can simplify things like validation and logging greatly.